# What are the server requirements of HTML5?

Tags: html5

From my understanding, the HTML5 is on browser side. Is there anything need to setup on the server to support HTML5? How do I verify the server fully support HTML5? Thanks.

Comment: I know there are some MIME mappings that need to be setup on the server, but this question may be better answered on stack overflow or superuser.

Comment: Thanks. I will try ask on SO. I thought I asked the server side question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An HTTP server knows that it's not an expert in parsing HTML like those "browsers" it keeps hearing about; it cares that it's HTML long enough to set the MIME type to `text/html` and to decide whether it should be compressed and whether it needs to get handled by an external handler, but that's all based on the file extension.

The contents of HTML are of no concern to a web server; no special requirements need to be in place to serve HTML5 content.

Comment: wrong... websockets must be supported by web server

Comment: @nonlinearly The websocket protocol was developed as part of the HTML 5 development process, but it isn't part of the HTML 5 spec.  It's a separate protocol that uses HTTP as a starting point but isn't HTTP and isn't HTML (or HTML5).

Comment: See also: http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html `was originally part of the HTML5 specification, but was moved to a separate standards document to keep the specification focused.`